# output python to csv regular

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

hello i'm new on python/scrapy world, i need to export my list of products to csv like this exemple:
[what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GixLB.png)
but i get this one:
[what i got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L9pK.png)

/////
**spider:**
/////

```
import scrapy
import csv
from escrap.items import EscrapItem

class EscrapSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tunisianet"
    allowed_domains = ["tunisianet.com.tn"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/385-logiciels-informatique-tunisie/"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "ajax_block_product")]'):
            item = EscrapItem()
            item['revendeur'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/@href').re('tunisianet'))
            item['produit'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/text()').extract())
            item['lien'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/@href').extract())
            item['description'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "product_desc")]/a/text()').extract())
            item['prix'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "price")]/text()').extract())
        data = [item['revendeur'], item['produit'], item['lien'], item['description'], item['prix']]
        out = open('out.csv', 'w')
        for row in data:
            for column in row:
                out.write(column.encode('utf-8'))
        return data
```

/////
**items:**
/////

```
import scrapy

class EscrapItem(scrapy.Item):
    revendeur = scrapy.Field()
    produit = scrapy.Field()
    lien = scrapy.Field()
    description = scrapy.Field()
    prix = scrapy.Field()
```

/////
**pipelines:**
/////

```
class EscrapPipeline(object):

    # put all words in lowercase
    words_to_filter = ['politics', 'religion']
    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        for word in self.words_to_filter:
            if word in      unicode([item['revendeur'],item['produit'],item['lien'],item['description'],item    ['prix']]).lower():
                raise DropItem("Contains forbidden word: %s" % word)
        else:
            return item
```

/////
**my setting:**
/////

```
BOT_NAME = 'escrap'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['escrap.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'escrap.spiders'
ITEM_PIPELINES = {'escrap.pipelines.EscrapPipeline': 1}
FEED_EXPORTERS = {
    'csv': 'escrap.escrap_csv_item_exporter.EscrapCsvItemExporter',
}
FIELDS_TO_EXPORT = [
    'revendeur',
    'produit',
    'lien',
    'description',
    'prix'
]
```

Comment: What do the items in `data` have? From the output that you're getting it looks like the data that you have in `data` could be not what you expect.

Comment: items in the data represent the products (seller name, product name, description ,,))
`data = [item['revendeur'], item['produit'], item['lien'], item['description'], item['prix']]`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create the csv file yourself when parsing items, scrapy can export by default to a csv file.

so change your `parse` method to:

```
def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "ajax_block_product")]'):
        item = EscrapItem()
        item['revendeur'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/@href').re('tunisianet'))
        item['produit'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/text()').extract())
        item['lien'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/@href').extract())
        item['description'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "product_desc")]/a/text()').extract())
        item['prix'] = '\n'.join(sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "price")]/text()').extract())
        yield item
```

later when calling scrapy you can call it with:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -o output.csv
```

Now you have all your items exported to a csv file.

If you still want to control it on your own pipeline, check here to [create your own exporter](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exporters.html#using-item-exporters). It would like this:

```
from scrapy import signals
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter

class CSVExportPipeline(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.files = {}

     @classmethod
     def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
         pipeline = cls()
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_opened, signals.spider_opened)
         crawler.signals.connect(pipeline.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
         return pipeline

    def spider_opened(self, spider):
        file = open('%s_products.csv' % spider.name, 'w+b')
        self.files[spider] = file
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def spider_closed(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        file = self.files.pop(spider)
        file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

To create your own pipeline make sure to [read](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html#item-pipeline) this entirely.

Comment: i would like to export them without -o output.csv ,
and the problem is i don't have an idea about item exporters :/

Comment: did it help to export your data?

Comment: please check how you should ask on SO, and that seems like an update on your question than an answer. The problem there is the same with your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36943255/export-python-data-to-csv-file?noredirect=1#comment61446150_36943255) you are writing to a csv file instead of returning items correclty.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set the cell where you want to write you data. Something like:

```
worksheet.write('A1','thing you want to write')
```

Or it may be default to write content in 'A'

Answer (score 0):

it export but not with the form i want, i want the form like this one :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/phYGp.png , but i got this one https://i.stack.imgur.com/StCDp.png .
here is my final class :

`def parse(self, response):
        item = TfawItem()
        data= []
        items = []
        out = open('out.csv', 'a')
        x = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "ajax_block_product")]')
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            item['revendeur'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/@href').re('tunisianet')[i]
            item['produit'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/text()').extract()[i]
            item['url'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/@href').extract()[i]
            item['description'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "product_desc")]/a/text()').extract()[i]
            item['prix'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "price")]/text()').extract()[i]
            data = item['revendeur'], item['produit'], item['url'], item['description'], item['prix']
            out.write(str(data))
            out.write('\n')`