# export python data to csv file

Tags: python, csv, scrapy

I'm trying to export my file via command line :

```
scrapy crawl tunisaianet -o save.csv -t csv
```

but nothing is happenning, any help?

**here is my code:**

```
import scrapy
import csv
from tfaw.items import TfawItem


class TunisianetSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "tunisianet"
    allowed_domains = ["tunisianet.com.tn"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/466-consoles-jeux/',
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        item = TfawItem()
        data= []
        out = open('out.csv', 'a')
        x = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "ajax_block_product")]')
        for i in range(0, len(x)):
            item['revendeur'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/@href').re('tunisianet')[i]
            item['produit'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/text()').extract()[i]
            item['url'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "center_block")]/h2/a/@href').extract()[i]
            item['description'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "product_desc")]/a/text()').extract()[i]
            item['prix'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "price")]/text()').extract()[i]
            data = item['revendeur'], item['produit'], item['url'], item['description'], item['prix']
            yield data
            out.write(str(data))
            out.write('\n')
```

Comment: why are you creating a item, and then passing that to a tuple?, and if you are already exporting to csv on the command line, why do you need `out.csv`?

Comment: thought out.csv will overwrite data for each time i executed the command but it's ok

Comment: didn't [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36902783/output-python-to-csv-regular/36903483#36903483) help?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are getting these errors:

```
ERROR: Spider must return Request, BaseItem, dict or None, got 'tuple' in <GET http://www.tunisianet.com.tn/466-consoles-jeux>
```

which specifically says what's wrong,  you are returning tuples as items, change your yield code to:

```
...
item['prix'] = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "price")]/text()').extract()[i]
yield item
```